# Integration of arcsin problem using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sympy, integral

[Integration using python][1]

$\int_0^{\infinity}\frac{sin^{-1}\left(2x\right)}{1+x^2}dx$

integration of (arcsin(2x))/(1+x^2) dx [infinity, 0]

I can't seem to solve this problem using python. Can anyone help me with the solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you already tried?  You tagged `sympy`.  Do you have a `sympy` attempt?

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it. But it isn't working. Here's what I tried.

x = smp.symbols("x")
f = smp.asin(2*x)/(1+x**2)
smp.integrate(f,(x,0,smp.oo))'

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, SymPy does exactly what it is supposed to do: it reduces a given integral as far as possible which is a number when the integral is well-defined and analytic. However, the integral in question is not analytic. In turn, SymPy returns the symbolic representation of it as it cannot be further simplified.

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x', positive=True)
f = asin(x)/(1 + x*x)
d = integrate(f, (x, 0, oo))
>d
```

[image]

Checking out [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+Arcsine%282x%29+%2F+%281+%2B+x%5E2%29+from+0+to+infinity) indicates how challenging this integral is; which is why only an approximation is provided.

In turn, a numerical integration scheme to approximate the value should be considered, e.g. methods from `scipy.integrate`.